# Hashtable using generic lists implementation

Tags: c, list, generics, hashtable

Can anyone please help me with an implementation of a hashtable using generic lists? So far, I got this, can anyone please tell me if this is the right way to go?

```
typedef struct HashTable {
    int key_len;
    int data_len;
    int num_buckets;
    HashEntry *buckets;
} HashTable;

typedef struct HashEntry {
    void* key; 
    void* data;
    HashEntry* next; //list for collision resolution
} HashEntry;
```

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for, but the order of declaration appears backwards. Unless you leaving out forward decls in your post

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot more like a linked list than a hash table IMHO.  A hash table should be something like an associative array with the hash as the key and the record as the value.